# When a big cassandra import is started, WMI process is going nuts

Tags: windows, cassandra, wmi

We have this problem with our cluster that every time we're starting to import lots of data, WMI process on our Windows machines is trying to eat as much of the processor power as it can. For example now the java cassandra process and WMI process are both taking 50% of the processor resources. The result is that nodes are dying randomly and the performance of the cluster seems to be degraded. Is there any way to prevent those two processes competing for resources?

We're using 64 bit Windows Servers 2012R2 running on Intel Xeons 2.4GHz and 8GBs of RAM. Cluster consists of three identical machines.

One short word of explanation - sometimes it's like that for hours, sometimes after a couple minutes it all calms down. Also sometimes after a period of peace between those two one node is going totally nuts and processor is occupied 99% by WMI and cassandra.

Comment: Which cassandra and cqlsh version are you using ?

Comment: It's Cassandra 3.10. As for cqlsh I don't know, but it's the one shipped with Cassandra 3.10 version.